# Single Sign Out in Grafana

Tags: apache, authentication, single-sign-on, reverse-proxy, grafana

I have implemented Single Sign On using Grafana. I have used reverse proxy and disabled the sign out feature in grafana. Now I want to logout of grafana after logging out of the main application. How this feature can be implemented in PHP without clearing all browser cache and cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the logout button `disable_signout_menu = false` and give `signout_redirect_url = "http://localhost/ldap/login.html"` to your application url so that user will not have access to grafana login page.

Answer (score 0):

That is a good one. Have you been able to use Grafana inside a PHP application so that when the test is running, it can get redirected to the Grafana dashboard? Or maybe embed a live - real time dashboard inside Php page?

Comment: Yes I have been able to integrate grafana with php application using reverse proxy. [Here are the steps followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51414460/how-to-use-ldap-authentication-with-grafana-and-wamp-for-single-sign-on/51626038#51626038). You can leave ldap if you are not interested with authentication and authorization.